# What is the "right way" to combine sync and drop_caches?

Tags: linux, performance, filesystems, disk-cache

When I need to do `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` with a `sync` beforehand, is it better to use

`sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` or

`sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.

Does it even matter because both commands are safe for the filesystem data? Or might the second version lose data in the process?

Comment: You only lose performance, not data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More like... you shouldn't *need* to do this at all. What's the root or underlying performance problem you're trying to correct with the drop_caches routine?

For the record, `sync ; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` is fine.

Comment: I wuld argue that the sync is superfluous as when dropping the cache the system will need to sync the contents to disk anyway. You don't lose data whatever you do.

Comment: I stumbled upon this gem while migrating and old system to a VM. There are some long running processes that seem to leak memory over time.